# Date formatting through Javascript - JQuery

Tags: javascript, datetime, date-format

Dates are always a kick in the nuts (at least for me) and I faced the fact that Javascript doesn't seem to have a method to format dates.

I'm trying to format a date to use the Google API which ask you for a date in this format: yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffffff (e.g. 2011-06-25T10:00:00.000+02:00)

I need to be able to read that kind of string and to produce one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often use jQuery plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-dateFormat

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat/master/jquery.dateFormat-1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var d = new Date();
    alert($.format.date(d, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'));
})
</script>
```

Comment: Yaiks! it works for query purpouses it's sad that doesn't support to convert dates from YYYY-MM-DD to DD-MM-YYYY doesn't it?

Comment: Do it yourself, it's two lines of code, or one if you use a regular expression: `'2011-03-21'.replace(/(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d)/, '$3-$2-$1')`.

Comment: Sorry for the late question on this answer - I have the script loaded, but always get JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'date' when I try to call  var msgTime = $.format.date(message[0].ActionMessageDt.toString(), "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");